# I don't see the External IP for my K8s application running with Istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Am working on deploying a sample application with Istio on k8s perhaps I don't see my External IP available after deploying it. I would really appreciate if someone can help on the same!

Thanks in advance!

[LoadBalancerIP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBs5r.png)

Answer (score 0):

The way LoadBalancer services get exposed/assigned an external IP will depend on where your cluster is running. Typically, the IP should be assigned automatically if you're running a cloud-managed k8s (Azure, GCP, AWS).

For running a local cluster using Minikube, Kind, etc., it's best to check their respective documentation on how to configure LoadBalancer services.

It's hard to say where your cluster is running, but I'd suggest you look at the specific k8s setups in [Istio's documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/platform-setup/).